# How to single out an hour value in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that can check to see if businesses in different time-zones are open due to their working ours (9am-9pm). I created functions to get the current time in each time-zone:

```
Portland_HQ = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
NewYork_HQ = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
London_HQ = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/London'))
```

I want to be able to extract the hour value of each function so I can create a if statement like so:

```
    if hour >= 9 and hour <= 21:
            some code happens..
```

Edit: I Don't know why I got so many downvotes, I didn't know about that attribute, new to Python and just trying to learn like everyone else. Really enjoy this community but sometimes it can be a little harsh for a beginner. Thank you for everyone that helped! I will use the .hour attribute.

Comment: have you tried `Portland_HQ.hour` ?

Comment: `Portland_HQ.hour`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: RTFM [Available Types](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#available-types) in `datetime` docs. Additionally, `help(datetime.datetime)` will show its attributes.

Comment: Don't know why I got so many downvotes, I didn't know about that attribute, new to Python and just trying to learn like everyone else. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the `hour` attribute:

```
if 9 <= Portland_HQ.hour <= 21:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Quite new to Python, and didn't know about this attribute. Will accept your answer once it allows me (still have 3 minutes).